# Turning GetLastError() into an exception

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project that uses a `Win32Exception` class in cases where there is an *exceptional* error. The `Win32Exception` class looks like this:

```
/// defines an exception based on Win32 error codes. The what() function will
/// return a formatted string returned from FormatMessage()
class Win32Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    Win32Exception() : std::runtime_error( ErrorMessage( &error_code_ ) )
    {
    };

    virtual ~Win32Exception() { };

    /// return the actual error code
    DWORD ErrorCode() const throw() { return error_code_; };

private:

    static std::string ErrorMessage( DWORD* error_code )
    {
        *error_code = ::GetLastError();

        std::string error_messageA;
        wchar_t* error_messageW = NULL;
        DWORD len = ::FormatMessageW( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
                                      FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                                      FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                      NULL,
                                      *error_code,
                                      MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ),
                                      reinterpret_cast< LPWSTR >( &error_messageW ),
                                      0,
                                      NULL );
        if( NULL != error_messageW )
        {
            // this may generate a C4244 warning. It is safe to ignore.
            std::copy( error_messageW, 
                       error_messageW + len, 
                       std::back_inserter( error_messageA ) );
            ::LocalFree( error_messageW );
        }
        return error_messageA;
    };

    /// error code returned by GetLastError()
    DWORD error_code_;

}; // class Win32Exception
```

The class works well in the situations it has been used in. What I would like to know is if there are any obvious cases where this will fail that I should be aware of. Any other gotchas, caveats, or general suggestions on improvements are welcome.

Please note that the boost library is not an option for this code.

Comment: In case you're wondering, this class is also used on WindowsMobile which doesn't have `FormatMessageA`. That's why it's converted from UNICODE to ASCII.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- This has already done by several people, including yours truly

  - https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/blob/master/LogCommon/Win32Exception.hpp
  - https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/blob/master/LogCommon/Win32Exception.cpp
- Ironically, your code is not exception safe.

  ```
  if( NULL != error_messageW )
  {
      // this may generate a C4244 warning. It is safe to ignore.
      std::copy( error_messageW, 
                 error_messageW + len, 
                 std::back_inserter( error_messageA ) );
      ::LocalFree( error_messageW );
  }
  ```

Note that if the `back_inserter` causes `std::bad_alloc` to be thrown, the memory allocated inside `FormatMessage` is leaked.

Comment: +1 for the memory leak I've missed! However the code you posted a link to is not thread safe, it uses static variable to store the result of what().

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yes, it is not thread safe -- I'm using it in a single threaded app only. (And the lack of thread safety is clearly marked in the comment right next to it :P ) If you need thread safety you can store a `std::string` inside the exception object itself, which I elected not to do for this particular library so that I didn't have to pay for `std::string` constructions when an exception is thrown. If you need thread safety, just call `GetCharMessage()` instead, which returns a `std::string` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't read comments when I read code :P hate noise. The proper way to do this is to have a `mutable` cache and to fill it when `what()` is called for the first time.

Comment: @ybungalobill: But then you have to pay for the construction of the `std::string` even when you don't need to use the error message.

Comment: agree. but an empty string is probably much cheaper. If it's *really* a problem you may try to store a mutable pointer to a heap allocated string.

Comment: Update: C++11 now requires that local statics be thread safe, so the thread safety argument above is no longer true.

Comment: The links are dead in the post, could please update it? (possibly by copying the most interesting bits in the answer itself)

Answer (score 3):

- What a coincidence! I use a similar code in all my projects! It is actually a good idea.
- This code is problematic:

  ```
      // this may generate a C4244 warning. It is safe to ignore.
      std::copy( error_messageW, 
                 error_messageW + len, 
                 std::back_inserter( error_messageA ) );
  ```

  It just trancates WCHARs to chars. Your can either use FormatMessageA explicitly to get a message in the current code-page (ok, you can't as you said), or make convention that all your stings are UTF-8 encoded. I chose the later, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful/1855375#1855375) why.
- Error message by itself may be not useful. Capturing the stack trace may be a good idea.

Comment: The `std::exception` from which `std::runtime_error` is derived defines the `what()` function as being `const wchar_t* what()`. That's why I converted the string to ASCII. Or are you saying I should use something other than `std::copy()` for the string conversion? I could switch to `::wcstombs()`, I suppose. This just seemed easier at the time.

Comment: Yep, use wcstombs, WideCharToMultiByte or copy as you do now and verify that the text is actually ascii. It's not critical though since FormatMessage probably returns ASCII on any sane system.

Comment: @PaulH: It's `const char *` from `what`, not `wchar_t` (I wish it worked that way) Difficulty with `wcstombs` is that you don't know what source encoding it expects, and you don't know what encoding it converts to. Considering you're working with a Win32 specific scenario anyway, you might as well just use FormatMessageA.

Comment: @Billy: OP said in a comment to his post that he can't use FormatMessageA on WindowsMobile.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Interesting. WideCharToMultiByte then.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Sorry.. thought I had already +1'd this. +1. Also, how would one capture a stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Realize this is old, but at least with VC++ 2015 you can throw a `system_error` that will do all this with the `system_category()` function:

```
try
{
    throw system_error(E_ACCESSDENIED, system_category(), "Failed to write file");
}
catch (exception& ex)
{
    cout << ex.what();
}
```

This would print: "Failed to write file: Access is denied"

Answer (score 1):

- `FormatMessage` may itself fail. Some neutral "Unknown error with code %d" might be in order for such case.
- Some error codes are not really errors (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS), depending on what user is expecting.
- Some system functions return their own error codes (notable example being `SHFileOperation`) that you must handle separately. If you want them to be handled, that is.
- Consider having additional information inside exception: where is exception being thrown from (source file and line), what system function caused exception, what were the parameters of the function (at least the identifying ones, like file name, handle value, or some such). Stack trace is also good.

Comment: <nitpicker corner>"Unknown error with code %d" actually I think it should be %u, or 0x%8x to be really cool.</nitpicker corner>

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to know is if there
>   are any obvious cases where this will
>   fail that I should be aware of. Any
>   other gotchas, caveats, or general
>   suggestions on improvements are
>   welcome.

The main I've problem I've had with such message retrieval has been `ERROR_SUCCESS`. It's rather perplexing when some operation fails, accompanied by error message "The operation succeeded". One wouldn't think that could happen, but it does.

I guess this is a special case of what Dialecticus noted, that "Some error codes are not really errors", but for most of those codes at least the message is generally acceptable.

The second problem is that most Windows system error message have a carriage return + linefeed at the end. It's problematic for insertion of messages into other text, and it breaks the convention for C++ exception messages. So, good idea to remove those chars.

Now, instead of repeating all that others have already noted, a few words about the design.

The `ErrorMessage` function would much more usable if was made public or moved out of the class, and took the error code by value, instead of taking pointer argument. This is the principle of keeping separate responsibilities separate. Promotes reuse.

The code in `ErrorMessage` would be more clear and safe and efficient if you used a destructor to deallocate the memory. Then you could also just construct the string directly in the `return` statement instead of using a copy loop with back inserter.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on a very similar class and after reading this thread tried to make the copying part exception-safe. I introduced a little helper class that does nothing but hold the pointer to the string returned by `::FormatMessage` and free it with `::LocalFree` in its destructor. Copying, assigning and moving is not allowed, so one cannot get into trouble.

Here is what I came up with in total:

```
class windows_error {
public:
    windows_error(wchar_t const* what);

    // Getter functions
    unsigned long errorCode() const { return _code; }
    wchar_t const* description() const { return _what; }
    std::wstring errorMessage() const { return _sys_err_msg; }
private:
    unsigned long _code;
    wchar_t const* _what;
    std::wstring _sys_err_msg;
};

// This class outsources the problem of managing the string which
// was allocated with ::LocalAlloc by the ::FormatMessage function.
// This is necessary to make the constructor of windows_error exception-safe.
class LocalAllocHelper {
public:
    LocalAllocHelper(wchar_t* string) : _string(string) { }
    ~LocalAllocHelper() {
        ::LocalFree(_string);
    }

    LocalAllocHelper(LocalAllocHelper const& other) = delete;
    LocalAllocHelper(LocalAllocHelper && other) = delete;
    LocalAllocHelper& operator=(LocalAllocHelper const& other) = delete;
    LocalAllocHelper& operator=(LocalAllocHelper && other) = delete;

private:
    wchar_t* _string;
};

windows_error::windows_error(wchar_t const* what)
    : _code(::GetLastError()),
      _what(what) {
    // Create a temporary pointer to a wide string for the error message
    LPWSTR _temp_msg = 0;
    // Retrieve error message from error code and save the length
    // of the buffer which is being returned. This is needed to 
    // implement the copy and assignment constructor.
    DWORD _buffer_size = ::FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
                                          FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
                                          FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
                                          NULL, _code, 0, _temp_msg, 0, NULL);

    if(_buffer_size) {
        // When calling _sys_err_msg.resize an exception could be thrown therefore
        // the _temp_msg needs to be a managed resource.
        LocalAllocHelper helper(_temp_msg);
        _sys_err_msg.resize(_buffer_size + 1);
        std::copy(_temp_msg, _temp_msg + _buffer_size, _sys_err_msg.begin());
    }
    else {
        _sys_err_msg = std::wstring(L"Unknown error. (FormatMessage failed)");
    }
}
```

Maybe this will be useful for some of you.