# Turning GetLastError() into an exception with Error string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, winapi, exception

This is very similar to:
[Turning GetLastError() into an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475157/turning-getlasterror-into-an-exception)

I also want to be able to add an `std::string` to the error:

```
class Win32Exception : public std::system_error
{
public:
    Win32Exception(std::string ErrorDesc) :
        std::system_error(GetLastError(),
                          std::system_category(),
                          ErrorDesc)
    {
    }
};
```

The problem is that at least in DEBUG builds of VS2015 the construction of `std::string` resets `GetLastError()`. So by the time the `Win32Exception` ctor. calls `GetLastError()` it always gets zero/no error.

I could use `const char*`, but I also want to use `std::wstring`, which means I need to convert it to `std::string` or `const char*` (because the `std::system_error` expects `std::string` or `const char*`), and that leads me back to the same problem that the error gets reset.

Is there some elegant solution on how to throw Win32 errors easily, having the exception class capture `GetLastError()` and being able to add arbitrary info with `std::string`'s?

Comment: IMO the call to `GetLastError()` should not be "hidden" in an exception class. `GetLastError()` is supposed to be called *immediately* after the error condition happened. I would rather give up the little convenience your class provides and just pass the last error value as an argument to `std::sytem_error`. Maybe one line more to write but less brittle code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rewrite exception class constructor so it will take error code as parameter so error code:

```
Win32Exception
(
    char const * const psz_description
,   ::DWORD const      error_code = ::GetLastError()
)
:   std::system_error(error_code, std::system_category(), psz_description)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting the `ErrorDesc` parameter by value. The `std::string` – its type – will be constructed as part of argument passing, and this happend before you call `GetLastError()` in the implementation.

To prevent the construction of the `std::string` you could accept it as a view of the passed argument. The following ideas come into mind:

1. The type of the parameter could be an [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (since C++17). `std::string_view` still could call Windows API functions in its ctor., so not an entirely proper solution.

   ```
   Win32Exception(const std::string_view& ErrorDesc);
   ```
2. Overloading on all possible string types.

   ```
   Win32Exception(const char* ErrorDesc);
   Win32Exception(const std::string& ErrorDesc);
   ```
3. A templated constructor using `const &`.

   ```
   template <class S>
   Win32Exception(const S& ErrorDesc);
   ```

The next problem will be at the construction of the base class `std::system_error`. You are passing it three arguments, two of which could call a Windows API function resetting the last error. Remember, that the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) of the arguments is indeterminately sequenced (see rule 14).

To force `GetLastError()` be called first, you could inject an additional base class `Win32ExceptionBase`.

```
class Win32ExceptionBase : public std::system_error
{
public:
    template <class S>
    Win32ExceptionBase(DWORD LastError, const S& ErrorDesc) :
        std::system_error(LastError,
                          std::system_category(),
                          ErrorDesc)
    {
    }
};


class Win32Exception : public Win32ExceptionBase
{
public:
    Win32Exception(const std::string& ErrorDesc) :
        Win32ExceptionBase(GetLastError(), ErrorDesc)
    {
    }
};
```

Now, when you construct a `Win32Exception`, `GetLastError()` will be called first. Passing `ErrorDesc` to `Win32ExceptionBase` ctor. will not call a function because it's a `const &` of a deduced type.

Instead of introducing the base class `Win32ExceptionBase` you can add an additional defaulted parameter to `Win32Exception` ctor., that should never be provided by the caller:

```
Win32Exception(/*view type*/ ErrorDesc, DWORD LastError = GetLastError()) :
    std::system_error(LastError,
                      std::system_category(),
                      ErrorDesc)
{
}
```

---

This will make the use of `Win32Exception` very convenient. Although, we should point out, that all this effort will not prevent resetting the last error at the call site, e.g. when the user is calling a function while constructing your class: `throw Win32Exception("ERROR: " + str);`.